# Putting down axioms for some symbols. Playing with their consequences qualitatively and symbolically. Building theories. The book?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, logic, model-theory

I am interested in the design and building of theories. By building theories, I mean putting down axioms of various kinds, over various fields, exploring their perhaps interesting, or probably boring, consequences.

I would like to know if there are books:

- perhaps with a historical bent, characterizing the thoughts that went behind the design of a particular system of axioms for a catalogue of theories;
- perhaps with a non-historical bent, just exploring axiomatization in general;
- perhaps with a "fun" bent, attempting to recreate a well established mathematical theory from scratch;
- perhaps that are clearly a text on abstract algebra, but one that explores qualitatively the various consequences of choosing particular axioms?

Does such a book exist, or am I dreaming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you :

> Robin Hartshorne, [*Geometry: Euclid and Beyond*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387986502) (2005)

and

> Ian Mueller, [*Philosophy of Mathematics and Deductive Structure in Euclid's Elements*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486453006) (1st ed 1981).

Both deal with *geometry* and have an historical bent (no "fun").

You can see also :

> Howard Eves, [*Foundations and Fundamental Concepts of Mathematics*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/048669609X) (1st ed 1990), with a nice Chapter 6 on *Formal Axiomatics*; it deals also with *algebra* and *number systems* (no "fun").

Regarding the development of modern algebra and axiomatics, see :

> Leo Corry, [*Modern Algebra and the Rise of Mathematical Structures*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3764370025) (2004).

With a different point of view, can be interesting also :

> PhilipJ Davis & Reuben Hersh, [*The Mathematical Experience*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0817682945) (1st ed 1981).

In conclusion, I think that it will be not easy to find references "helping" with the "design of a particular system of axioms for a catalogue of theories".

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure that there's a single book that fits your varied desiderata. But, just addressing the first of the bullet points, the history of the axiomatization of geometry (and then geometries, plural) is surely an obvious place to start. There is a rich but very readable article by Marvin Greenberg [here](http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Greenberg2011.pdf). And then, for a lot more, there is Greenberg's book mentioned in his biblio.

Comment: I dare to add : Robin Hartshorne, [*Geometry: Euclid and Beyond*](http://www.amazon.com/Geometry-Euclid-Beyond-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/0387986502) and Ian Mueller, [*Philosophy of Mathematics and Deductive Structure in Euclid's Elements*](http://www.amazon.com/Philosophy-Mathematics-Deductive-Structure-Elements/dp/0486453006).

Comment: You can see also : Howard Eves [*Foundations and Fundamental Concepts of Mathematics*](http://www.amazon.com/Foundations-Fundamental-Concepts-Mathematics-Dover/dp/048669609X) with a nice Chapter 6 on *Formal Axiomatics*.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Dear Mauro, thank you *very* much for your Howard Eves suggestion!

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Could you put down an answer with your contributions? It is not necessary, unless you want internet points, which I would be happy to provide.